# Laravel's seeJson doesn't work for collection

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to utilize Laravel's seeJson method for checking a collection response but it doesn't seem to work as I expect it to. Why does it work this way and what should I do to test this properly?

```
Unable to find JSON fragment [[{"created_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46","email":"batz.aracely@yahoo.com","id":1,"name":"Mr. Enrique Wehner DVM","updated_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46"}]] within [[{"created_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46","email":"batz.aracely@yahoo.com","id":1,"name":"Mr. Enrique Wehner DVM","updated_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46"},{"created_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46","email":"halvorson.gaston@hayes.org","id":9,"name":"Talon Monahan I","updated_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46"},{"created_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46","email":"ilynch@gmail.com","id":2,"name":"Araceli Gulgowski","updated_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46"},{"created_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46","email":"kattie.stracke@aufderhar.com","id":10,"name":"Baylee Abshire Jr.","updated_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46"},{"created_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46","email":"lenore08@klein.com","id":4,"name":"Nicola Gusikowski","updated_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46"},{"created_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46","email":"reilly.trace@yahoo.com","id":5,"name":"Doris Sauer Sr.","updated_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46"},{"created_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46","email":"rhegmann@hotmail.com","id":6,"name":"Camilla Romaguera","updated_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46"},{"created_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46","email":"robel.dortha@hotmail.com","id":3,"name":"Dr. Eudora Turcotte DVM","updated_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46"},{"created_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46","email":"vturner@hamill.com","id":8,"name":"Ashton Shields","updated_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46"},{"created_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46","email":"walsh.herman@gmail.com","id":7,"name":"Devyn Bradtke","updated_at":"2016-03-05 15:12:46"}]].
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Test and controller code:

```
public function testSeeingUserList()
{
    $users = factory(App\User::class, 10)->create();
    $this->get('/users/')
         ->seeJson($users->toArray());
}

public function listUsers()
{
    return App\User::all();
}
```

Comment: You don't have to convert it to `$users->toArray()`

Comment: @JilsonThomas, seeJson demands an array